# Editing linear scale to display as quartiles

Tags: vega

I have a Vega spec that displays a value along a scale that’s been manually broken into four segments. The segments are currently displayed along a linear scale, but in reality they represent pre-calculated quartiles. How can I instead display the segments with each using 25% of the width of the chart, stretching the values along the scale within the segment?

Current chart:

[image: screenshot of current Vega chart]

Here is the full Vega spec I’m working with:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "Chart showing nesting score for selected location.",
  "width": 294,
  "height": 16,
  "padding": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "data_segments",
      "values": [
        {"segmentLabel": "min", "segmentStart": 0, "segmentEnd": 26.3},
        {"segmentLabel": "low", "segmentStart": 26.3, "segmentEnd": 42.9},
        {"segmentLabel": "mid", "segmentStart": 42.9, "segmentEnd": 54.8},
        {"segmentLabel": "high", "segmentStart": 54.8, "segmentEnd": 70.7}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "signals": [
    {"name": "signal_score", "value": "38"}
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "scale_x",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {
        "data": "data_segments",
        "fields": ["segmentStart", "segmentEnd"]
      },
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.05,
      "round": true
    },
    {"name": "scale_y", "domain": [0, 1], "range": "height"},
    {
      "name": "scale_segment_color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": ["min", "low", "mid", "high"],
      "range": ["#f6eff7", "#bdc9e1", "#67a9cf", "#02818a"]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "data_segments"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "scale_x", "field": "segmentStart"},
          "x2": {"scale": "scale_x", "field": "segmentEnd"},
          "y": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 0.1},
          "y2": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 0.9},
          "fill": {"scale": "scale_segment_color", "field": "segmentLabel"},
          "stroke": {"value": "white"}
        }
      }
    },
    
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "data_segments"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"signal": "scale('scale_x', signal_score) - 3"},
          "x2": {"signal": "scale('scale_x', signal_score) + 3"},
          "y": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 0},
          "y2": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 1},
          "fill": {"value": "white"},
          "stroke": {"value": "grey"},
          "tooltip": {"signal": "signal_score"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Here’s how I’ve worked around this in practice, but it’s a solution outside of Vega. In my javascript before calling the Vega chart, I now use the segment start/end values and the actual score value to calculate the score’s position along a linear scale of 0–100. I then plot the point using that value, but report the actual score in the tooltip. It's not a great solution, but it works. I’d love to just send the actual score to my Vega spec and have it handle the calculations and plotting, however.